# Determine if the given claim is true or not.Justify your answer briefly.

Tags: calculus

(a)There is a function $f$ such that $f(0)=-1$, $f(1)=5$ and $f'(x)<2$ for all $x$.

(b) $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(\tan x)=\frac{d}{dx} \arcsin(\sin x)$

(c) If $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x$ in their domains,then $f-g$ is a constant function.I cannot decide which way i proof, especially (a) I dont have any idea  and (c) i could not find a counter example

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. We are not here to blindly answer homework questions - please show us what work you have done so that people know what you already know and can tailor their answer to your knowledge level

Comment: Firstly thank you.Ofcourse you dont have to do my homework and i just hurry up to share and i forgot to write my opinions about the questions

Comment: For (a) if $f$ be continuous then the mean-value theorem makes negative answer!